# Prestashop database Schema

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

is it possible to create a graphical representation of specific object in database Schema and all it relationships with all linked metadata, views, and stored procedures assocated with this object? Example: I want to define a logical relationships between “Data Sheet” tab on Prestashop product page and the rest elements in a database schema.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (partially) - use the mysql workbench. It has reverse engineering db tools

see [mysql dev wb link](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

This will generate diagram of the tables + relationships. Stored procedures, views, trigger etc are not going to be supported (too complex). You will just have to browse and reverse them yourself.

Comment: can this be done with online tool, using server side scripting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find PrestaShop's new Physical Data Model here: http://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/a-new-physical-data-model-available-for-prestashop/

Answer (score 0):

There is a MySQL workbench model in the dev directory of the Prestashop distribution (although the last one I looked out was out of sync with the actual release database schema, although that could have been a development release). I would make that my first point of call. Unfortunately it won't show up every relationship between tables though.

One of the quickest ways to do analysis is to take a snapshot of the database, insert a particular record (user, order, customer, data sheet etc.), take another snapshot, then diff them.